# Использование функции в качестве аргумента

Tags: javascript

В общем нужно написать функцию func(a, gen), которая принимает на вход 2 функции, a и gen, где gen — функция-генератор. func возвращает новую функцию-генератор, которая при каждом вызове берет следующее значение из gen и пропускает его через функцию a. Пример:

```
function createCounter(start, step) {
  return function(){
    if (start === undefined)
      start = 0;
    if(step === undefined)
      step = 1;
  start+=step;
  return start - step;
  };
}

var counter = createCounter(1, 1);
function pow(x) { return x * x; }
var powGen = func(pow, counter);

console.log(powGen()); // 1
console.log(powGen()); // 4
console.log(powGen()); // 9
console.log(powGen()); // 16
```

При этом, необходимо сделать так, чтобы в качестве gen можно было указать функцию с аргументами, и при вызове

```
function add(a, b) { 
  return a + b; 
}

var powAdd = func(pow, add);
console.log(powAdd(1, 4)); // 25 = (1 + 4) ^ 2
console.log(powAdd(2, 5)); // 49 = (2 + 5) ^ 2
```

Один из способов решения:

```
function func(a, gen) {
  return function() {
    return a(gen());
  };
}

var func1 = func( pow, createCounter(1, 1) );

func1(); // 1
func1(); // 4
func1(); // 9
func1(); // 16
func1(); // 25
```

Но этот и другие варианты не выдерживают условия задачи. Я хочу разобраться как написать правильно тело функции func.
Ссылка на задачник (задача №4): http://dkab.github.io/jasmine-tests/?spec=4

Comment: я запутался где должен быть генератор и где не должен быть

Comment: не сильно понятнее стало. Что за функция pow в конце?

Comment: самое непонятно: как возможен вызов _func(square, add);_ если `add` - не возвращает функцию генератор???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле формулировка задачи немного не корректна.

Корректные требования можно узнать при проверке:

1. Функция fmap(mixin, fn) должна возвращать функцию
2. Возвращаемая функция должна принимать любое количество аргументов и передавать их функции fn
3. должна вызывать функцию mixin для результатов функции fn

По данным пунктам довольно просто написать необходимую функцию:

1. функция, которая возвращает функцию:

   ```
   function fmap(mixin, fn){
       return function(){
           ...
       }
   }
   ```
2. Есть несколько вариантов передать вызову внутренней функции аргументы из внешней

   1. используя [метод `apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

      ```
      function (){
          fn.apply(null, arguments);
      }
      ```
   2. воспользовавшись [spread-оператором](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) и [rest-параметрами](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

      ```
      function (...args){
          fn(...args);
      }
      ```
3. вариант очевиден: `mixin(fn(...));`

Итого все в сборе может иметь следующий вид:

```
function fmap(a, gen) {
  return function(...args){
    return a(gen(...args));
  }
}
```